# How can I set up CiviMember to meet these requirements?

Tags: civimember

I'm wondering how I can set up CiviCRM to fit these requirements, do I create one membership with price sets or multiple memberships? How Would I go about the dynamic price changing? 2nd and last year??

Thanks!

For Honorary members, year the member became honorary is indicated.

Member type: Members will enter one of the following. If they are joining or renewing, the amount of membership is automatic.

1st year practice       $50 
2nd year practice       $100
Regular             $150
Part-time           $75
Retired             $30
Resident            $40 or $20 *
Medical Student     $20 or $10 **
Associate           $50

* Residents who join in their first year pay $40 for the duration of their graduate medical training program. Residents who are in their 2nd or last year of their training program pay $20 each year.

** Medical students who join in their first year pay $20 for the duration of their undergraduate medical training program. Students who are in their 2nd or last year of their training program pay $10 each year.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for all different membership types.

And on the signup page to describe properly for who it is.

The problem with pricesets is that it is much more difficult to get priceset info to show up in searches, in exports, in reports, in batch imports. So if you would do all (or a few) with the same membership types, you often only see the paid price difference, and not the underlying reason why they paid differently. You obviously can guess, but often you would want to see the reason (different option chosen in the priceset).